# How to find quantity of individual characters in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would need the program to accomplish getting the quantity of individual characters from list data that has been stored in a series. Here is an example of what I would like the program to accomplish:

```
char_list = ['LNTS', 'AGTS', 'LMFS', 'PGST']
#end result (higher to lower frequency)
S : 4 
T : 3
L : 2
G : 2
N : 1
A : 1
M : 1
F : 1
P : 1
```

I know this can be accomplished with regular Python, but I am trying to find the Pandas equivalent. So far I have gotten:

```
pd.Series(char_list).value_counts())
```

But this returns the quantity of the whole sequences versus their individual characters. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` isn't particularly well suited for this sort of problem. It *can* be done, but in the end you're either just going to iterate over the Series, as opposed to the list (really not different) or if you truly want to do it in a different `pandas` way it will involve some slow `.str`. methods.

The easiest way you get what you want is `collections` + `itertools`. Use a `Counter` and chain all the separate words together. Then you can make a `Series` out of the dict and sort it.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(char_list))).sort_values(ascending=False)

S    4
T    3
L    2
G    2
N    1
A    1
M    1
F    1
P    1
dtype: int64
```

---

If you want to use `pandas` you could `split` the words into each letter, drop the empty string at the start and the end, then `explode` and take the `value_counts`. But this is a lot more complicated and likely slower than the above.

```
s = (pd.Series(char_list)
       .str.split('')
       .str[1:-1]
       .explode()
       .value_counts())

S    4
T    3
L    2
G    2
N    1
A    1
M    1
F    1
P    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @HenryEcker Oh smart. That's a different enough solution to add yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue in solving this problem is that each cell contains a string value, so any `pandas` opertaions will consider the whole cell as a single unit. To remedy this, it is necessary to transform the data so that each cell is a single-character string.

There are many approaches with varying efficiencies, but they all fundamentally rely on turning a column of strings into a column of single-character strings.

1. Creating a [`chain.from_interable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) then applying [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd

char_list = ['LNTS', 'AGTS', 'LMFS', 'PGST']
output = pd.Series(chain.from_iterable(char_list)).value_counts()
```

2. [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) each string into a list, then [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and `value_counts`:

```
import pandas as pd

char_list = ['LNTS', 'AGTS', 'LMFS', 'PGST']
output = pd.Series(map(list, char_list)).explode().value_counts()
```

3. [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) or [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) list then `explode` and `value_counts`:

```
import pandas as pd

char_list = ['LNTS', 'AGTS', 'LMFS', 'PGST']
output = pd.Series(char_list).apply(list).explode().value_counts()
```

```
import pandas as pd

char_list = ['LNTS', 'AGTS', 'LMFS', 'PGST']
output = pd.Series(char_list).map(list).explode().value_counts()
```

All options produce:
`output`:

```
S    4
T    3
L    2
G    2
N    1
A    1
M    1
F    1
P    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Some timing information via %timeit:

```
%timeit pd.Series(chain.from_iterable(char_list)).value_counts()
273 µs ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit pd.Series(map(list, char_list)).explode().value_counts()
358 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit pd.Series(char_list).map(list).explode().value_counts()
428 µs ± 19.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit pd.Series(char_list).apply(list).explode().value_counts()
508 µs ± 36.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[From @ALollz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765744/15497888):

```
%timeit pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(char_list))).sort_values(ascending=False)
215 µs ± 7.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit pd.Series(char_list).str.split('').str[1:-1].explode().value_counts()
677 µs ± 14.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
char_list = ['LNTS', 'AGTS', 'LMFS', 'PGST']
pd.Series(x for x in ''.join(char_list)).value_counts()
```